# Check Whether links are clicked in body of mail with sendGrid API

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a number of links which needs to be sent in the mail. How can i track whether the links in the mails are clicked or not, and which links are clicked.
I do not have control over the links which are sent so cannot use google analytics or something on that links.
I need some mechanism in the sendgrid dashboard that can notify whether links were clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by passing `tracking_settings` in the message object that needs to be passed to sendGrid.

```js
tracking_settings: {
  click_tracking: {
    enable: true,
    enable_text: true
  }
}
```

`tracking_settings` : Determines whether you would like to track the metrics of how your recipients interact with your email.

`click_tracking` :  Allows you to track whether a recipient clicked a link in your email.